# Android WebView Onclick ProgressBar

Tags: android, webview

Yes i read almost all the topics about webview progress bar, tried almost everything. But they do not work for me, my app crashes when i use the examples.

I am using local (ondevice) html in my webview app and i want to show progress bar (notification) after the links clicked on that html. here is my code.

Activity_Main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.dijitalyayincim.cekmekoy.cekmekoy_web.MainActivity">

   <WebView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main_Activity.java

```
package com.dijitalyayincim.cekmekoy.cekmekoy_web;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar ab =getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    ab.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());


}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    }
}
```

MyAppWebViewClient.java

```
package com.dijitalyayincim.cekmekoy.cekmekoy_web;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

/**
 * Created by ahmet.sevinc on 18.11.2016.
 */

public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("cekmekoy.info")) {
        return false;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked perfectly for me.. Give it a try

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class About_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    private boolean isRedirected;

    private ProgressBar progress;
    String url = "Your URL";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        startWebView(webView, url);

    }

    private void startWebView(WebView webView,String url) {

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                isRedirected = true;
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                isRedirected = false;
            }

            public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
                if (!isRedirected) {
                    if (progressDialog == null) {
                        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(About_Activity.this);
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                        progressDialog.show();
                    }
                }

            }
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                try{
                    isRedirected=true;

                    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        progressDialog = null;
                    }



                }catch(Exception exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle arrow click here
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if there is any)
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="in.invis.navigationdrawer.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks, i have changed About_Activity MainActivity, Your Url to "file:///android_asset/www/index.html" but now i get this error   webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); Error:(38, 46) error: cannot find symbol variable webView

Comment: u need to have a layout file which has a webview element

Comment: YESS when i changed android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview" to android:id="@+id/webview" in activity_main.xml everything worked...

Comment: Happy to help..Always

Comment: you are using progress dialog. OP asked for progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
 mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mWebview);
 mWebview.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

 /**
 * Load Webview with using Progressbar
 */
 public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;

}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for your prompt response, now i have Error:(65, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable progressBar, i already import android.widget.ProgressBar;

Comment: this give a little delay in loading progress bar , just between start loading of webpage and click on btn to start webview